The shape of j-invariant
Definition of j-invariant: $$j(\tau)=1728\frac{g_2(\tau)^3}{\Delta(\tau)}=1728\frac{g_2(\tau)^3}{g_2(\tau)^3-27g_3(\tau)^2}=1728\frac{E_4(\tau)^3}{E_4(\tau)^3-E_6(\tau)^2}$$
If you look at this equation, the degree of $g_2$ in the numerator is $3$, the degree of $g_2$ in the denominator is $3$, and the degree of $g_3$ is $2$, so when you actually perform the division, it becomes $0$ as in the comment below, which is an invariant.
My question here is, if the goal is to make the division invariant, I think you can substitute $g_3$, which has a degree of $2$, into the numerator, but is there a mathematical motivation or reason for creating a form like the modern j-invariant?
Edit:
I searched more about this question, I could find this table.
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 & i & \omega  \\ \hline
E_2 & \frac{3}{\pi} & \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\pi}  \\
E_4 & 12\eta(i)^8, \frac{3\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^8}{64\pi^6} & 0  \\
E_6 & 0 & \frac{27\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})^{18}}{512\pi^{12}}  \\
\end{array}$$
Looking at this table, I can understand to some extent why the formula was set up this way, but did Felix Klein have this in mind when he created the formula from the beginning? If not him, who else assigned $g_2$ to the numerator instead of $g_3$?
